# Filter out images which don't have IPTC metadata

Tags: image, metadata, exif, exiftool, iptc

I like ot filter out images and move them to another directory that either doesn't have,

- Title
- Description
- Headline
- Keywords

filled.

If any of the above missing, move to new directory.

I think Exiftool could do this

Comment: I could do it with Bridge but the collection is enormous and Bridge can't handle it

Comment: How about making life easy for anyone wishing to answer you by providing an image that has these fields set to easily recognisable values like "MYTITLE", "MYDESCRIPTION", "MYHEADLINE" and "MYKEYWORDS" so we can be sure of meaning the same fields?

Comment: I didn't know I could upload files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic exiftool command would be:
`exiftool -if "!$Description or !$Headline or !$Subject or !$Title" -Directory=/path/to/moved/ /path/to/source`

This checks each of the tags you list and if any one doesn't, it will be moved to the directory indicated by the `Directory` tag.

This command assumes that you are using IPTC Core (aka XMP) tags.  If you file only has the older IPTC IIM/Legacy tags, it will not get moved, even though Bridge would display the file as having the data.  This is because Bridge will read data from either the IPTC IIM or IPTC Core, whichever tags exists, to fill out the data it displays.

A more complete command which would check to see if at least one of the IPTC Core/IPTC IIM tags have data would be
`exiftool -if "(!$Description and !$Caption-Abstract) or !$Headline or (!$Subject and !$Keywords) or (!$Title and !$ObjectName)" -Directory=/path/to/moved/ /path/to/source`

If you are running on Mac/Linux change the double quotes into single quotes in order to prevent the shell from interpreting the tag names as shell variables.

Comment: Thanks mate again! You are my hero